# 'First in' in Sencha Touch adding items to the container

Tags: sencha-touch

Can I add an item to the container as the first one rather than appending all existing ones.

From what I understand `this.add([item])` will add item as the last one, however I would like it to apper it on the top of the screen before anything else has been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [insert](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-insert) method of container like this:

```
this.insert(0 , item);
```

where it would appear depends on your layout.